# Testflight iOS Crash debugging, cannot figure out source

Tags: ios, crash, external, testflight

I am having a testflight user reporting random crashes which I cannot seem to replicate. The relevant section of their crash log is here:

```
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   iMavlink                        0x00000001001045a4 0x10009c000 + 427428
1   iMavlink                        0x00000001001049fc 0x10009c000 + 428540
2   iMavlink                        0x00000001000ee54c 0x10009c000 + 337228
3   iMavlink                        0x00000001000b9354 0x10009c000 + 119636
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182a894bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:760)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182a8947c _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:506)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182a8eb84 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844 (inline_internal.h:1063)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ff4d50 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1613)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ff2bb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628 (CFRunLoop.c:2718)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182f1cc50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000184804088 GSEventRunModal + 180 (GSEvent.c:2245)
11  UIKit                           0x0000000188206088 UIApplicationMain + 204 (UIApplication.m:3772)
12  iMavlink                        0x00000001000dbc94 0x10009c000 + 261268
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000182aba8b8 start + 4 (start_glue.s:78)
```

Im not sure where to even begin with this. It dosent seem to have any reference to my code which I can see, but I am new to debugging in Xcode using testflight so I am probably missing something really obvious.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!
Tom

Comment: You need to get the crash report symbolicated. Frames 0, 1, 2, and 3 are pointing to your code, but without symbolication you won't see which part.

Comment: Thanks Kerni. I have tried doing this, but it just comes up with hidden. Looking at the dev forums it seems this is a itunesconnect bug when you submit with binary enabled?

Comment: Try to download the symbols with Xcode organizer from the machine you created the build, the symbols you get via that might work better.

Comment: That didn't work, I just ended up disabling bitcode for my future uploads and that worked